# Are there any differences between the 3D versions of Star Wars and the previous ones?

Tags: star-wars

At the moment, I wonder if I should watch the new Star Wars movies (the remastered 3D versions) that are coming up in the cinemas soon. I have heard that there are several minor and major differences between the original Star Wars movies and the new versions, so I wonder, what are those differences? Obviously, there is the 3D gimmick, but what other changes are known by now?

I went to the [Wikipedia article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_changes_in_Star_Wars_re-releases) but it barely mentions the 3D movies.

Comment: Sounds like a list question.

Comment: First view this, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_changes_in_Star_Wars_re-releases, than go here http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/in-what-order-should-the-star-wars-movies-be-watched

Comment: Thank you for the wiki article, but it barely mentions the 3D movies. As far as I know the first movie is out by now, so there should be information about it.

Comment: I have been told there are no new retcons that it is just the same move (at least for PM) done in 3d.  And here is was hoping that Jar Jar would be retconed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as march 2012, the only 3d Star Wars movie released is [Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I%3a_The_Phantom_Menace#3D_release). The previous version is the one released on Blu-Ray in September of 2011.

> The film was released as scheduled, and along with the conversion of the film to 3D, **Yoda's model was also changed to the one used in Revenge of the Sith**.

The Blu-Ray version of also feature a CGI Yoda, So the only changes is the Yoda model **might** been updated for the 3D conversion. (I will try to find a confirmation that the model is different from the one used for the Blu-Ray).

As far as new/modified scene, nothing changed from the Blu-Ray version.

Comment: I believe that the Yoda model on the Blu-Ray for Episode I is the CGI version.  As they haven't released 3d on Blu-Ray, I don't know what Yoda looks like there.  Source: I have the Blu-Ray