# Where'd those guys on the Millennium Falcon go?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

So I'm re-watching Star Wars as I occasionally do, this time using the amazing [Machete order: IV, V, II, III, VI.](http://static.nomachetejuggling.com/machete_order.html) I'm watching the theatrical releases, cause I'm old school like that, when I realize that the scanning troopers go on but they never go off. On top of that, there isn't a chance later because everybody leaves the ship and gets back to it at the same time. So I throw in my Special Editions, thinking somebody must have dropped a scene when reconstructing the theatricals. No dice. Troopers go on, no troopers come off.

**So, what happened to those troopers?** Did Han and Chewie kill them and space the bodies afterward? Did they hand them over to the Rebellion off camera? To be clear, I was wondering if it ever got addressed in the Expanded Universe.

Comment: Short term, I'd bet they stuffed them in the smuggling storage area's Han et al hid in. Once they left the Death Star, I'd have to guess they were handed off to the Rebellion. Lukcy them I guess, considering what happened to the DS.

Comment: There is no greater thrill than the thrill of spacing.

Comment: +1 just for pointing me to the Machete order. This guy is a genious. It all makes sense now!

Comment: One of the guards is the famous [TK-421](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TK-421).

Comment: Is it just coincidence that the same question just came up in [Darths and Droids](http://www.darthsanddroids.net/)?

Comment: @beta Thanks so very much... now I'm going to have to make my way through that ENTIRE archive.

Comment: I still like [my order](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/in-what-order-should-the-star-wars-movies-be-watched/40754#40754) better, although it is based on the same flashback idea.

Comment: The dupe question has a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Star Wars radio play added a lot more background to the movie (the serial totalled about 6.5 hours) making use of Lucas' notes and writings that were not filmed - including a bit more information on the unfortunate scanning crew and stormtroopers.

From the [Star Wars wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Scanning_crew_BT-445):

> The two crewmen and the stormtroopers were later found unconscious
>   aboard the Falcon shortly after a firefight had broken out in
>   Detention Block AA-23. The crewmen were taken to an infirmary and
>   later perished in the destruction of the Death Star.

Comment: Anyone know where I can find the radio plays nowadays?  I had them on cassette recorded off the radio way back in the 80s, but they're long since gone from my collection now.

Comment: @BBlake Why not [ask a new question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)?

Comment: @BBlake and here's a question asking about the [availability of the Star Wars radio play](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/33545/2868).

Comment: @BBlake: There's a big website that sells all sorts of things.  It's called http://Amazon.com.  If you go there and search, you'll find different vendors selling the radio plays for the original trilogy on CD or cassette.  And there's also a site called http://Google.com.  If you search there, they'll give you links about the radio plays and their shopping service will give you links to where you can buy copies.

Comment: Alright smartass.  :)