# Is Essos a safe place when the winter comes?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In other words, are the white walkers able to cross the Narrow Sea? We do know that they cannot swim, but could the freeze it?

Comment: [No proof](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/168185/53012) whether Viserion breathes ice or fire

Comment: Okay, but the question still remains. The White walkers do have some "icy aura". Could it actually be that strong to freeze the Narrow Sea?

Comment: I would say the Night King can freeze lakes and stuff. But then he'd have done it earlier in episode 6. I think, unfortunately. This is too speculative of a question and violates our Future Works Policy

Comment: @Martin Again, no proof to support that the White Walkers or the Night King can freeze water bodies. So, Essos is a safe place for now.

Comment: I think this is an interesting, but very speculative question

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no proof that Viserion is breathing ice. For all we know, it can be blue fire. Nor do we have any proof  that the Night Walker(s) can freeze water bodies.
2. Essos is supposed to be a safe place, at least according to what we know till now, this is, that **the Dead cannot swim**.

Comment: Who says they can't swim? Just because they waited around the Island till Dany arrived? If that's so, how do we explain them jumping in and out of Ice Holes?

Comment: @Aegon Yes. That was the reasoning which Jon and co have given to Cersei. So, that's the only way one can validate this.

Comment: If they could swim, they could pass the wall at eastwatch from the sea.

Comment: Blue fire? That’s ridiculous! Everyone knows that [fire is red!](https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/gameofthrones/images/4/41/Wildfire_explosion.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150328212702)

Comment: @Aegon: “Just because they waited around the Island till Dany arrived?” They also stood there on the docks at Hardhome, instead of pursuing Jon and company through the water. “how do we explain them jumping in and out of Ice Holes” When did they do that?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Which is also something that irked me (But it is not really relevant as books do not apply to that specific scene). Also they did it when they were dragging Tormund inside water. And that one Wight which was drowned by Hound came out of the water.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Also, that fire is green :P Signature flame of Wildfire.

Comment: @Aegon: oh yes, dragging. Although I think that happened reasonably close to the big rock than Jon and company were on, so maybe the water was shallow enough there for them to be standing on the bottom? Or a rock? Or three or four other wights?