# Old movie about alien eggs inside cave

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I was born in 1994 and remember watching this movie with my mom when I was young, but even back then it seemed somewhat old.

In the beginning of the movie I think it's scientists or such who enter a cave, but it has what seems like a lot of webs in front of it covering the entrance. The deeper they go, the darker it gets, and then they discover alien eggs.

I cannot remember the rest of the movie. It could have been horror; I don't know (almost like an alien nest). But then in the end they are leaving that exact same cave I believe.

Comment: Probably the original 1979 movie _[Alien](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(film))_?

Comment: Makes me think of them finding the giant ant eggs in the old movie 'Them'

Comment: I'm sure those things just turned out to be comfy pillows, perfect for lying down and taking a nap with in this nice, dark place after such a long and tiring walk. So, so sleepy...

Comment: It's probably not Alien, because you definitely would remember the hatchling alien putting sulfuric acid on the scientist's head and then the scene afterwards, with the chestburster baby alien. it's a superior movie too, and the scientists get eaten. it's helpful to know other facts like if they had space-suits.

Comment: Yeah, I guess *Alien* is an old movie. I feel old ;-).

Comment: If it weren't for the cave aspect, the webs and eggs would have lead me to suggest ["The Web"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0500271/), an episode of [Blake's 7](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076987/?ref_=tt_ov_inf).

Comment: Why has this not been closed yet? 5 answers that match the question is a clear sign of needing more focus.

Answer (score 22):

Given the scant details you give, *Alien* seems like the best candidate: but I'd expect it's known by everyone, so probably you're looking for a different film.

There are two that come to mind: they're both low-budget Italian spin-offs released in 1980, in the aftermath of the aforementioned *Alien*.

The less known of the lot is *Alien 2: On Earth* which, despite the confusing title, hasn't anything to do with *Alien* but took advantage of the name for a little exposition. **It follows a group of speleologists who find a cave filled with alien eggs**, so perhaps this is the one you're looking for.

It was released in 1980: [here's the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_2:_On_Earth), which is surprisingly rich. And someone uploaded it on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rTdMekH528) as well; sadly it's in Italian but you can check it just to see if it fits your memories.

The other is [*Alien Contamination*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/228871/58193) (see the linked answer for details).

Comment: "I'd expect it's known by everyone" - not always! https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154621/movie-about-a-boy-two-men-a-robot-and-a-war

Comment: @AGB Believe it or not, there are even people who confuse Alien and Star Wars... :-)))

Answer (score 12):

Finding a clutch of alien or monster eggs is a pretty common motif in science fiction (especially science fiction horror) films, so there are probably a good number of films that will be reasonable matches for your description.  I am going to mention two of them (in two separate answers) that seem reasonable hypotheses from what you might have seen.

Another possible film is *[The Nest](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095719)* (1988).

The plot summary, [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nest_(1988_film)):

> The sheriff of this small island town called North Port has a roach problem in his house. According to the local exterminator Homer, it turns out the whole town is about to have a big roach problem. Pets, and then people, begin to disappear or turn up dead and mutilated.
>
> Although Sheriff Richard Tarbell is dating Lillian, the owner of the local eatery, his high school sweetheart Elizabeth Johnson returns to the island after a four-year absence and their romance blooms again. Elizabeth happens to be the daughter of the town's mayor, Elias Johnson, who is in cahoots with an evil corporation called INTEC that has been secretly breeding mutant roaches that are immune to normal insect repellants. They also seem to have the ability to assume the form of anything they kill, leading to some animal/roach hybrids and even 2 roach/human combos.

*The Nest* is, in my opinion, more gross than scary, with tons of large cockroaches crawling around the sets and supposedly devouring everything they come across.  The one really memorable and creepy scene, however, is when Lillian goes exploring in the cave where the roaches are breeding.  It features some hanging egg-sac structures in the cave.  That scene is available as [a preview at IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/video/vi2447487257?playlistId=tt0095719&ref_=tt_ov_vi).

The whole film is also on YouTube, but the audio and video are not synced up correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Follow-up answer to my other post, as suggested. The other one is *Alien Contamination*, somewhat a better film: alien eggs are central to the plot here too but I don't remember any caves.

You're lucky because this film has [a page with lots of information on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contamination_(film)) as well. And [YouTube has the full length movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woH5AZx8XTM).

Answer (score 4):

Could it have been [*The First Men in the Moon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Men_in_the_Moon_(1964_film)) (1964)? Based on a H.G. Wells story I think.

The explorers land on the moon and discover a large metal door leading into a cave system going deep below the surface. It's a long time since i saw the film so but I do recall the honeycomb structures containing eggs.

It had some weird little insect alien guys, very distinctive spacecraft too.

Quite a charming little film, well worth a re-watch for the Victorian steampunk tech.

Trailer:

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve your answer by [edit]ing in some details about alien eggs and caves, to match what was noted in the question.

Comment: added what i remember from the film which was relevant to the original question. thanks for the tip

Comment: A lesser-known Harryhausen classic.

Answer (score 2):

Finding a clutch of alien or monster eggs is a pretty common motif in science fiction (especially science fiction horror) films, so there are probably a good number of films that will be reasonable matches for your description.  I am going to mention two of them (in two separate answers) that seem reasonable hypotheses from what you might have seen.

One possibility is *[Contamination](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082000/)*, 1980 Italian production (which desperately tries to convince you it takes place in the United States).

The plot summary, [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contamination_(film)):

> A large ship drifts into New York Harbor, seemingly abandoned. The ship is discovered to be carrying large containers of coffee, hidden inside of which are a series of football-sized green eggs. The crew sent in to explore the ghost ship find the mutilated remains of the former crew gathered in one place, and they soon discover the reason why: when disturbed, the green eggs explode, spraying a viscous liquid over everything. The liquid is toxic to living creatures, and causes the body to immediately explode.
>
> The military's answer to this phenomenon is Colonel Stella Holmes. She establishes a link between the green eggs and a recent mission to Mars that ended badly for the two astronauts who descended to the planet. One of them disappeared, and the other, Commander Hubbard, had a breakdown and subsequently became an alcoholic. When pressed, Hubbard agrees to help Holmes in her investigation of the insidious plot to bring the deadly eggs to Manhattan, and it takes them, along with sarcastic New York cop Tony Aris, to a Colombian coffee plantation. All is not as it seems; Hubbard's former astronaut colleague is apparently alive and well and living under the influence of a monstrous alien cyclops, which is using mind control to further its plot to flood the world with the green eggs and wipe out human life on Earth.

Obviously a ripoff on *Alien*, the film features eggs found on a deserted freighter (an ordinary ship though, not a spaceship), which shoot dangerous goop at people.

The whole thing is available on YouTube.  Here it is, cued up near the eggs' appearance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surpized no one mentions [*Gargoyles*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068622/) where Cornel Wilde and Jennifer Salt play:

> An anthropologist/paleontologist and his daughter, while travelling through the southwestern U.S., stumble upon a colony of living, breathing gargoyles.

The scene near the end where just hatched young stand and embrace their keepers sounds just like what you are looking for. Bernie Casey made great use of what would have been a minor role.

Answer (score 1):

The film you may be trying to remember is from around 1991. It is a low budget shock fest of a film called *[The Rift](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099701/)* (AKA *Endless Descent*).

> Siren II, a submarine under the command of Capt. Phillips, ventures into the deep on a mission to recover the missing Siren I. Their quest is hindered when the submarine becomes entangled in a patch of toxic seaweed.

The eggs you mentioned are in the film, the cave, everything. It is available for free on Tubi TV. I've been trying to remember this film for a long time. I originally though it starred Amanda Pays from the original Flash TV series, but the gal in it looks vaguely like her.