# Scifi movie identification about a guy on the run from a police organisation that can predict crime before it happens

Tags: story-identification, movie, hard-sci-fi

- Watched it early 2000's
- Set sometime on the future
- In a futuristic world where the police have the ability to catch criminals before they commit the crime

Basic plot details that I can remember:

- main protagonist is a former police officer who is now on the run from the police, because of a crime that he hasn't yet committed (he himself has no idea what this crime would be)
- the man tries to clear his name and find flaws in the crime catching system.

Comment: This is a film directed by the most successful director of the last 50 years, and starring the most successful actor of the last 50 years. How this question has been asked has blown my mind.

Comment: @Darren popularity alone doesn't mean a movie is easy to identify. This case however was easy, pasting part of OP's description [into google](https://www.google.com/search?q=In+a+futuristic+world+where+the+police+have+the+ability+to+catch+criminals+before+they+commit+the+crime).

Comment: Is there a sonic shotgun in your movie? Pew~BOOM!

Comment: Looks like I need to go ask a question about the name of an old space movie with laser swords that I saw a while ago....

Comment: Huh, thats pretty funny - I checked and there are lots of questions about things that happened in that space movie with laser swords, ... but not a single question asking what it's name is.  I'm off to get loads of free rep!!

Comment: @JK you mean https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154621/movie-about-a-boy-two-men-a-robot-and-a-war/154624#154624?

Comment: You left out “based on a novel written by one of the most influential authors of the last 100 years”.

Comment: @JK. I tried to do that as an April-fools joke a few years and the lash back from the comminuty was quite hard... Ahem

Comment: @Darren what statistic(s) are you using to determine " the most successful X of the last 50 years"? Just curious.

Comment: @stannius the statistics of “off the top of my head”. It was a throwaway comment, not a Wikipedia article that requires citations. That said; Spielberg is the highest grossing director of all time (according to Wikipedia). And Cruise is near the top of highest grossing actors (especially after removing ensemble movies like Avengers), plus there are other metrics such as popularity and influence.

Comment: @Darren I don't think _any_ "popularity metric" is a good criterion for determining whether or not an identification question should be asked. I've never _ever_ heard about this movie before, until very recently after stumbling on an excerpt on Youtube, and I wasn't even aware it was a Spielberg movie, nor that the main actor was Tom Cruise. That being said, when I tried searching it up (after knowing its existence), it was very easy to find with just a few keywords.

Comment: @Clockwork Please point to the screen where I said this shouldn't have been asked.

Comment: @Darren you know that 87% of statistics are made up on the spot.

Comment: @MarkRansom But that's OK, because 93.476% of people don't believe them anyway…

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Is this ***[Minority Report](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181689/)*** (2002)...?

> In a future where a special police unit is able to arrest murderers before they commit their crimes, an officer from that unit is himself accused of a future murder.

The story takes place in a mid-21st century version of Washington, D.C. where a special "Precrime" division of the police uses a trio of clairvoyant mutants known as "precogs" to predict the date and time of imminent murders, enabling them to identify and arrest the would-be perpetrators before the crimes have been committed.

The main character is one of these Precrime officers, but ends up on the run from the law himself after he's predicted to commit a murder in the near future.

Comment: Why not mention that it's based on [a novelette by P. K. Dick](https://archive.org/details/Fantastic_Universe_v04n06_1956-01/page/n5/mode/2up)?

Comment: @user14111 - I predicted that you would, and didn't wish to deny you that opportunity.

Comment: @LogicDictates that is something that could not have happened if you had not predicted it, and as such nicely sums up the story.

Comment: I read the title in HNQ and thought "Minority report?"  I'm glad I didn't have the minority guess :D

Comment: @LogicDictates yes that's the one!! I can't believe I forgot the title.