# Prior to The Empire Strikes Back, did anyone predict that Darth Vader is Luke's father?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

Every once in a while, I hear about how Darth Vader's name translates to "Darth Father", so those who spoke a foreign language had a clue that he was someone's father.

One high profile example of this is *Pitch Perfect*, where a character who had never seen *The Empire Strikes Back* predicts the twist ending:

> Beca: [Movie endings] are so predictable, like, the guy gets the girl, and that kid sees dead people, and Darth Vader is Luke's father.
>
> Jesse: Oh, right, so you just happened to guess the biggest cinematic reveal *in history*?
>
> Beca: "Vader" in German means "father". His name is literally "Darth Father".
>
> Jesse: Huh.

Personally, I think that Beca is full of it because "Vader" is a Dutch word, not German (although "Vater" is).

But it did raise the question: prior to the release of *The Empire Strikes Back*, did anybody actually predict that Vader is Luke's father? Or is this just a case of Monday morning quarterbacking?

Comment: >Native dutch speaker here. When I was young I figured it out and the twist was meaningless to me, it was annoyingly obvious (given the desired impact of the twist). Granted: this happened many years after the film came out, and the twist was common pop-culture knowledge, but as far as I can remember I had no idea myself, Star Wars was just an old tape I had and at 5 or 6 I watched it and the name lended itself to giving it away (who knows whether I was influenced by general popculture though, just giving my anecdotal evidence).

Comment: As you can see in the dupe, Prowse (the actor who portrayed Vader) confidently predicted it

Comment: Relevant, but not a direct dupe; [Origin of Darth Vader's name](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28174/origin-of-darth-vaders-name)