# Why did Palpatine pick 'Vader' as a name for Anakin?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, darth-sidious, revenge-of-the-sith

When Anakin turned to the Dark Side Darth Sidious obviously saw fit to give him a new name:

> **PALPATINE:** Henceforth you shall be known as Darth...Vader.
>
> **ANAKIN:** Thank you, my master.

I've seen the question that's [already been asked](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28174/origin-of-darth-vaders-name) about the **out-of-universe** reason why **George Lucas** landed on the name Vader. I'm interested in whether there's an **in-universe** explanation for why **Palpatine** decided to call him what he did.

Was it just a random name plucked out of thin air? Did Palpatine pick it because he knew that Padmé was shortly due to give birth? Is there any preexisting connection between the name 'Vader' and the Dark Side of the Force?

Comment: Hmm. Sidious = Sneaky. Maul = Aggressive. Tyrannus = Megalomaniacal. Plageius = Medical. Vader = ???

Comment: He had to think of a negative word beginning with "in" -- so he could then remove the "in" from it.

Comment: Are you picking a name for _your_ apprentice?

Comment: @Terriblefan took me a second

Comment: @Valorum - Vader = father. To mock Anakin for being of questionable parentage ("Your father is a midichlorian!")

Comment: @Terriblefan Now I'm imagining if he had named him Darth Credible.

Comment: Palpatine, who was originally Dutch, had daddy issues. On the other hand, he luvshish fahja und zo er nannte seinen Lehrling... Der Vader.

Comment: @Valorum Vader = Traitor. He destroyed the Jedi Order from within.

Comment: Because Darth Bobo does not instill fear.

Comment: @NZKshatriya - speak for yourself. I've seen "Tripping the Rift" and that clown terrifies me.

Comment: @Omegacron  But Six more than makes up for Bobo :P

Comment: It was probably from a local pop song. "You're so Vader. You probably think this series is about you. You're so Vader..."

Comment: @Devsman Based on Anakin's personality, probably should have named him Darth Fantile.

Comment: "Darth Icky" means you don't have to question anything about what George Lucas thinks.

Comment: Darth Garth ...

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Per the Matthew Stover novelization, the name "Vader" was plucked from the Force itself (emphasis mine):

> Darth Sidious laid a pale hand on Anakin's brow. "Then it is done. You are now one with the Order of the Dark Lords of the Sith. From this day forward, the truth of you, my apprentice, now and forevermore, will be Darth ..."
>
> A pause; **a questioning in the Force - An answer**, dark as the gap between galaxies - He heard Sidious say it: his new name.
>
> Vader.
>
> <sup>*Revenge of the Sith: The Official Novelization* Chapter 17: "The Face of the Dark"</sup>

But there's no indication of what it means, or why the Force chose it for him.

Comment: Darkness, obviously. Darth Darkness.

Comment: Maybe Palpatine saw into the future and knew what the name would be, and so had to give Annakin that name - Bootstrap paradox?

Comment: @Alistair86 My working (headcanon) theory is that the Force chose a name meaning "Father", because prophecy

Comment: @JasonBaker *vader* is the Dutch word for father.

Comment: @Glorfindel https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NNcS.jpg

Comment: Darth Skippy was already taken.

Comment: @user100464 ...so was Darth Barney.

Comment: Ah yes, the good ol' Force Come Up With Sith Lord Names power. An often overlooked yet integral part of one's Dark Side training.

Comment: See, this is why you have a Sorting Hat, so you can ask these things

Comment: I expect that your headcanon is also Matthew Stover's; otherwise I'm not sure why he'd have bothered to included this little tidbit about how Palpatine came up with the name.

Comment: Palpatine tossed his Ouija board after it suggested "Quijibow" 7 times.

Comment: @user100464 - Darth Skippy was of course Jar-jar's father. "Jar-jar, mesa your fadder!"

Comment: @GorchestopherH Kwyjibo

Answer (score 0):

I personally thought Sidious picked the name as a subtle mockery of Anakin. Sidious is the only one who knows that Anakin and Padme were married, so theres a good chance he probably knew she was pregnant too. Plus Palpatine worked along side Padme for years while she was Queen and he was a senator. He probably suspected something at a certain point. According to another comment, the force "revealed" the name to Sidious, and its not like the force isn't all-knowing so the name just naturally fit Anakin's situation. As it was her specific death in childbirth that is the inciting incident to him becoming a sith. So does work out rather well.