# What would Luke's Sith name have been if he turned to the Dark Side?

Tags: star-wars, sith, luke-skywalker, return-of-the-jedi

At the end of *Star Wars Episode VI: Return of the Jedi*, Luke comes very close to turning to the Dark Side. If he had killed Darth Vader and became Darth Sidious's apprentice, what would his Sith name have been?

Is there any canon information that suggests what it would have been? Or is this something George Lucas has given an answer to in an interview?

Comment: I doubt it was even raised as a possibility, given how central this is to the plot.

Comment: related : http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150505/why-did-palpatine-pick-vader-as-a-name-for-anakin

Comment: Darth Famous, because he'd be infamous for his betrayal.

Comment: I would have thought Darth Whiner would have been appropriate...

Comment: Based on the first movie, Darth Cestuous.

Comment: It was _definitely_ Darth Joker; or the lesser known Darth Trickster

Comment: I like Darth Joker myself!

Comment: In Legends EU, Luke *did* fall to the Dark Side at one time ("Dark Empire" comic, when he apprenticed to a Palpatine clone). But he did not take on a Darth name before returning to the Light Side. There is a rumor that Luke *might* go Dark in the sequel movie trilogy, so maybe we will see him as a Darth in Disney canon...

Comment: Darth Zoon, since Zoon is son in Dutch

Comment: Darth Grappen (dutch for Joke)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Luke briefly joined the Dark Side in the comic *Dark Empire*. He also pledged himself to the Sith Assassin Galen Marek in a non-canon DLC to *The Force Unleashed*. He does not receive a Sith title in either case.

I don't have the exact quote, but he apparently sarcastically expresses fear of becoming Darth Starkiller in the Legends novel *Outcast*. Ironically, had Darth Vader raised him, this likely would have been his title, as Vader assigned it to [his secret apprentice](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galen_Marek) as a code name.

Unfortunately, nothing else appears to be known about the matter.