# Was there a given reason that Sidious didn't plan for Vader's name?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, darth-sidious

In [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150505/why-did-palpatine-pick-vader-as-a-name-for-anakin) question and especially it's accepted answer, it is established that the name 'Vader' was plucked from the Force in the moment of his rechristening.

Now, Sidious had been planning to seduce Anakin Skywalker to the dark side for, well, a lot of time. Is there a reason given in the novels, novelisations or anywhere else which explains why - despite all his planning, scheming, manipulation and preparation - he never planned for what 'Darth' his new, best-ever, more powerful than himself apprentice would become?

Surely you would think of it, plan for it, try different titles out - even think of it as 'The Vader Project' or similar? Is it perhaps part of the Sith tradition?

**Why did Darth Sidious leave the name for Darth Vader out of his meticulous preparations?**

Comment: The other answer indicates that a Sith name comes **at the appropriate moment** through the will of the Force. Why would he need a Sith name before then?

Comment: @Valorum - It doesn't say that explicitly. And I'm not suggesting he *needed* his name beforehand, just wondering if there is a reason it wasn't planned for. Your comment is likely the right answer - but it doesn't explicitly say that all Sith names come to the master at the moment of their turning and that preparation is inappropriate.

Comment: Sith name should somehow define him, and induce powerful Dark side emotions. Considering that name is given at the beginning of Sith's "career", it is doubtful it could be chosen without help of the Force. For example, who would have know that Anakin being a father would influence his fateful decision to terminate Sith Order ?

Comment: @rs.29 - Maybe the same person or metaphysical power which knew that Count Dooku would become a Sith dinosaur ;)

Comment: If "I" can think of a cool name for someone "on the fly", then it stands to reason that a powerful Sith lord could as well.

Comment: Sheev Palpatine was an educated man with a large vocabulary. There were many, many, descriptive adjectives that he could think of "on the fly". Each new Sith lord was given their Sith name at the whim of their master -- and it was generally based on a cardinal attribute that they possessed.